# Cryptograms in invisible ink

Tags: cipher

Solve the followng encrypted message.

> --2b1-21-1b112----b1b---21-b--12--1----b1b---b2-12-1--b22---2b21--211---b--121b-121-b21bb--b2-----211-1-b2b1---1b-12----2b21--211---2112b112-12-111-b2-----21b-12----2b21--211---2112b112-12-111-b2

Be brave and frail, and you'll surely be able to see the answer!

Comment: So you want us to be braille?

Comment: any hints for the people??

Comment: @dmg **d**i**m**ethyl**g**lyoxime?

Comment: I'm very braille now, but I still don't see. Perhaps I'm blind? =)

Comment: @Tryth Seems I miscalculated this one a bit. I expected getting the Braille connection to be the hard part, and after that for everything to be easy. Anyway, it did get solved relatively quickly. All's well that ends well!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The message reads:

> Fire and ice, and death was coming. But he was steel. He was steel.

(the final line of Chapter 13, *Floating like Snow*, in *The Path of Daggers*, book 8 of *Wheel of Time*; the "he" referred to is Rand al'Thor).

It is encrypted like so:

> The message is written in braille. I wouldn't have sen that without dmg's comment, but once he had pointed it out and I had seen the other heavy hints, it seemed to be obvious.
>
>
>  Braille letters are written in a grid of 2×3 dots. The message has 195 letters, which is divisible by three. The four characters encode one pair of horizontal dots: The dash means no dot, the `1` means the first or left dot; the `2` means the second or right dot and the `b` means both dots.
>
>
>  So the first letter made up of `--2` is `⠠`, which means the next letter is capital. The next letter `b1-` is `⠋` or F. The message also makes use of abbreviations like `⠯` for "and". [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Braille) has a detailed description on how Braille is used for English.

Comment: Brilliant, I tried it the other way around, but with no luck :)

Comment: @dmg: Thanks for the leg up. Without your comment, I woudn't have known where to start. Seems I got lucky with my first idea to transform the message to braille.

Comment: Well done M Oehm and @dmg! See also my comment on the question.