# A Shadowy Encounter

Tags: cipher, story, visual

In an attempt to contact the Puzzling Secret Enterprise (what PSE *really* stands for) you managed to get a meeting in an alley. A shadowy figure approaches you, he has his hood up and you can't see his face. He runs his hand along the wall until he reaches you.

After a brief conversation you are told that if you want to join PSE you must have another meeting. However the only way you will know where to meet is if you solve the following puzzle:

[image]

It appears to be a series of half moons

## Where is the next meeting?

Comment: @Emrakul, GPR: Oh no, Beastly Gerbil is onto us!

Comment: @Deusovi mwa ha ha!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is

> A braille representation of the word, Cafe

He runs his hand along the wall until he reaches you.

> Because he's blind?

The half moons

> Appear to be raised bumps

Comment: Correct, can you explain a bit more elaborately? For instance 'shadowy' encounter and the clues for braille?

Comment: Blind is correct and shadowy is because the half moons are the shadows caused by the bumps, well done I'll accept when I can.

Answer (score 5):

The next meeting is

> at the CAFE,

because the "shadowy half moons" are in fact

> Braille writing, which I decoded using this image:
>
>  [image]

I realised the method of solution as soon as I saw the image in the question, but there are also clues in the story:

> "*A shadowy figure approaches you, **he has a hood up and you can't see his face**. He **runs his hand along the wall** until he reaches you.*" suggests that he's blind and can't see his way to you. The "*alley*" in which you meet him might also be a **blind** alley.

Comment: Oh Sconibulus beat you to it but you'll get the accept if you explain a few more of the clues

Comment: @Beastly I didn't need any clues - the answer was obvious as soon as I saw the image :-) Nevertheless, edited.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find a way of making the bumps subtle, best I could come up with was the shadows caused...

Comment: @Beastly [Here's](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/13335/5373) how to do it more subtly ;-) (and wow, in retrospect that puzzle looks damn hard even to me!)